# How to remove Important dates section from Django User view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to remove **Important dates** section from django Admin User view.

[image]

Tried this:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('last_login', 'date_joined',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

But it's saying:

```
"Key 'last_login' not found in 'UserForm'. Choices are: email, first_name, groups, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_name, password, user_permissions, username."
```

How to remove this section from default User view django admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to do this:

**1) You can use css:**

```
- Inspect element in browser.
- IN css file add css for these ids:
     display:none;
```

**2) You can use js file:**

```
- Hide or delete the elements by their ids(Ids you find by inspecting element.)
```

Comment: Thanks @rahul mehra.